# How would you rerender part of template without using 2 templates [Django]?

Tags: python, html, ajax, django

I want to rerender template.html with data from a python function in my views.py file. Basically, when an onclick event occurs im using ajax to make a GET request with template data. Now I just want to display the results of the function that is being called. The solutions I've seen so far, propose to use 2 templates where you simply use the "include" tag. Are there any other django tags or ajax properties that can accomplish this using a single template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a python package [django_render_partial](https://pypi.org/project/django-render-partial/) which appears to be able to achieve what I am looking for. Using 
`render_partial` tags in my template to render results from python function calls.

EDIT:

Instead of needing this package, it is actually possible to return any empty list while using `render()`. Then you can update that same list with another function in views.py but, will also need to return it using the same render function. Note: You will need to have your list defined outside of both functions and update it using the `global` keyword. Additionally, you will also need to refresh the template page.